# How to pass data to AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

Can anyone tell me how to pass data to the jsp making the AJAX call ? This is what I am trying:

Here is my AJAX call:

```
     $.get("gridedit.jsp", { before: "row", time: "2pm" })
               .done(function(data) {
                 alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
               });
```

here is my gridedit.jsp

```
    <% String b=request.getParameter("before");

    if(b.equalsIgnoreCase("row"))
     {
System.out.println("ROW ROW ROW your boat");
        out.println("bummer");
    } %>
```

i want to store the value returned from gridedit.jsp into a javascript variable. How should I do this ?

please help

thanks

EDIT:

here is what i also tried

```
    $.ajax({
                url: "gridedit.jsp",

                async: true,
                cache: false,
                type:"GET",
                data: {
                    before:'row',
                      },
                      error: function(msg) { alert(msg); },
                      complete: function (xhr, status) { alert('complete: '+status); }

            });
```

i get two alerts, the first one says

```
    [object][object]
```

and the second one says

```
    error
```

can anyone figure out whats going on ?

please help

thanks

Errors;

so here i what i tried

```
      $.ajax({
                url: "gridedit.jsp",
                //dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                type:"GET",
                data: {
                    before:'row'
                      },
                      error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { alert(jqXHR);
                      alert(textStatus);
                      alert(errorThrown);},
                      complete: function (xhr, status) { 
                          alert('jqXHR:'+xhr);
                          alert('complete: '+status); }

            });
```

i get the following alerts in order:

jqXHR:
           [object][object]

testStatus:

```
      parseerror
```

errorthrown:

```
      Unexpected end of input
```

can anyone please help me in solving this ? my gridedit.jsp does this->

```
          <%String b=request.getParameter("before");
          System.out.println("b is here !" + b);
                        out.println("HELLO");%>
```

please help

thanks

Comment: I'm not positive on the java syntax, but that looks ok to me. What are you expecting to happen and what is happening instead? Did you check your javascript console and browser's network tab for errors?

Comment: -1 for not showing actual behavior, error messages. Please take the time to put details in your questions, that will only help you so that more people look at your question

Comment: thanks @Jason. I was hoping that the alert would pop up but it does not

Comment: thanks @Juan. i dont get any error messages. i just want to access the data sent by my gridedit.jsp thats why i was trying to pop up an alert to see whether any data is being passed or not. when i check the logs, the "ROW ROW ROW your boat" string gets printed. However I do not see the alert

Comment: If you are debugging in firefox, install the firebug add-on. There is a panel that can show the outgoing ajax request, and the response that (could) come back.

Answer (score 4):

Try number two:

I have an ajax request that looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/someplace",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    data: {
        number0: 0,
        key: littleKey
    },
    success: function(data, status)
    {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

and it works as is expected.

And you can specify get with `type : "GET"` in with the other options.

Maybe try having your .jsp print some data no matter what, and also print what data it is receiving.

Comment: thanks @Shade, you mean i can just do a out.println("Hello"); in my target JSP and the alert will pop up ?

Comment: well, start with that and check to see if the request is going out, and you are getting a response back. But this way, even if the .jsp isnt getting the data, it would still send something back, if the connection works.

Comment: i tried the above approach but i get the same result. when i check the logs, the "ROW ROW ROW your boat" string gets printed. However I do not see the alert

Comment: does it say anything else in the logs? anything indicating an error? And try putting 'test' outside of the <% %> tags and running again

Comment: no, there is no other error. i tried writing test before the scriptlet tags and it works like just as usual

Comment: So there was an alert with 'test' in it? If so, there needs to be output from inside the tags that doesnt go to the log and needs to get sent back to the website.

Comment: no, i just typed test before the beginning of the scriplet tags. there was no alert

Answer (score 0):

It is in a variable, the data variable in the anonymous function passed to .done()

Whatever you need the data returned by gridedit.jsp to do, the easiest way to have anything done with it is to use it in that function. Right now all you are doing with it is making a popup containing the returned data.

Comment: If the popup was showing the data, I don't think the OP would be asking this question

Comment: Ah, I didnt know the popup wasn't showing, I just figured he/she wanted use the data somewhere else in another script for something else.

Comment: the [object][object] is json. One way to view what the json is, is looking through firebug. once you are looking at the ajax request (it calls it a XHR), click on the request and then there should be a tab labled JSON. click on it and it expands the object structure.